# Is it possible to bind hotkeys to external tools in SharpDevelop?

Tags: ide, sharpdevelop

I want to bind Ctrl-Alt-N to an External Tool (Nant build) in SharpDevelop, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpDevelop currently does not support having a shortcut for an external tool. You could try using the [NAnt addin](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2005/10/15/NAntIntegration.aspx) that ships as a sample with the SharpDevelop source code. This should give you better integration than using an external tool.